# How to Import excel with additional input in laravel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I try to use Maatwebsite/Excel to import data from excel sheet. but it's not working properly. Show an error "Undefined array key "std_id"". I see many solutions in stackoverflow but didn't solved.
Please, help me to out from this error.

> Controller

```
public function excel_store(Request $request)
 {
   
 Excel::import(new StudentImport($request->institute_id,$request->academic_year_id,
            $request->session_id,$request->section_id,$request->std_category_id,$request->group_id), $request->file('file'));

 return redirect(route('excel.index'));
        
    }
```

ImportModel

```
class StudentImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
    protected $institute_id;
    protected $academic_year_id;
    protected $session_id;
    protected $section_id;
    protected $std_category_id;
    protected $group_id;

    public function __construct(  $institute_id,   $academic_year_id
    ,   $session_id,   $section_id,  $std_category_id,   $group_id) 
    {
        $this->institute_id = $institute_id;
        $this->academic_year_id = $academic_year_id;
        $this->session_id = $session_id;
        $this->section_id = $section_id;
        $this->std_category_id= $std_category_id;
        $this->group_id = $group_id;
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Student([
            
            'std_id'=> $row['std_id'],
            'roll' => $row['roll'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'gender_id' => $row['gender_id'],
            'religion_id' => $row['religion_id'],
            'father_name' => $row['father_name'],
            'mother_name' => $row['mother_name'],
            'mobile_no' => $row['mobile_no'],
            'institute_id' => $this->institute_id,
            'academic_year_id' => $this->academic_year_id,
            'session_id' => $this->session_id,
            'section_id' => $this->section_id,
            'std_category_id' => $this->std_category_id,
            'group_id' => $this->group_id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Excel Formet

```
std_id | roll | name | gender_id | religion_id | father_name | mother_name | mobile_no
```

here is my Migration file

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('institute_id');
        $table->string('std_id');
        $table->integer('academic_year_id');
        $table->integer('session_id');
        $table->integer('section_id');
        $table->integer('std_category_id');
        $table->integer('group_id');
        $table->string('roll');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('gender_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('religion_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('father_name');
        $table->string('mother_name');
        $table->string('mobile_no');
        $table->foreign("gender_id")->references("id")->on("Gender");
        $table->foreign("religion_id")->references("id")->on("Religion");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you only inject $request in your class? Are you sure there is std_id key in $row?

Comment: @MisterDebug yes std_id is present in excel file. and I dont know how to inject $request in class. give me an example, please.

Comment: Instead of StudentImport($request->institute_id,$request->academic_year_id,
            $request->session_id etc...) just inject $request :)

Comment: @MisterDebug it's not working

Comment: Which error do you have ?

Comment: @MisterDebug in studentimport have 6 perameter

Comment: Of course you need to change your construct too

Comment: @MisterDebug show this error (Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'religion_id' for column 'gender_id' at row 1)

Comment: can you add your migration file pls in original question?

Comment: @MisterDebug I update my question and add migration file, please check

Comment: Arf i don't see why. Before return new Student... Can you add dd($row) ; pls?

Comment: @MisterDebug dd($row) array:9 [▼
  "std_id" => 202206003
  "roll" => 3
  "name" => "Gggg"
  "gender_id" => "1"
  "religion_id" => "1"
  "father_name" => "Hhhhh"
  "mother_name" => "Jjjjjjjj"
  "mobile_no" => 4184576843
  8 => null
]

Comment: @MisterDebug without dd (SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'std_id' cannot be null)

Comment: And instead of dd($row) try dump($row) what's the last dump before exception?

Comment: You're try importing only one row from your excel or there are other rows?

Comment: @MisterDebug multiple row

Comment: So there is a row that doesn't respect the format, check your file:)

Answer (score 0):

Just return like below:

```
return Excel::import(new StudentImport($request->institute_id, $request->academic_year_id, $request->session_id, $request->section_id, $request->std_category_id, $request->group_id), 'student-import.xlsx');
```

Comment: XLSX file is not fixed. its upload by user.

Comment: Ok, on that scenario, use `$mimeType = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();` It will return you the file's mime type. After that pass the mime type as the second argument to the import method as well.

Comment: @S Ahmed Naim now show this error ( Incorrect integer value: 'religion_id' for column 'gender_id' at row 1)

Comment: May be foreign key doesn't exists. Please cross check the foreign key ids.

Comment: @S Ahmed Naim $table->foreign("gender_id")->references("id")->on("Gender");
            $table->foreign("religion_id")->references("id")->on("Religion");

Comment: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'religion_id' for column 'gender_id' at row 1